# Spring redirect is not working when i have path parameters in method signature

Tags: java, html, spring

The below is the code to display all employees

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/displayAllEmps")
public ModelAndView displayAllEmps() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("dispAllEmps");
    List<Employee> employees = employeeService.fetchAllEmps();
    modelAndView.addObject("employees", employees);
    modelAndView.addObject("listMsg", "<br>Employees List!!!");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

the below method is successfully redirecting me to the employee list page

```
@RequestMapping(value="/updateEmployee",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateEmployeeUsingObject(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee, Model model){
    employee.setFirstName("Changes TEsting");
    employeeService.updateEmployee(employee);
    List<Employee> employees = employeeService.fetchAllEmps();
    model.addAttribute("employees", employees);
    model.addAttribute("listMsg", "<br>Employees List --- After updating Employee");
    return "redirect:displayAllEmps";
}
```

but when I am redirecting from the below method its not working. URL is also little bit strange in the browser

```
@RequestMapping(value="/deleteEmployee/{empId}")
    public String deleteEmployee(@PathVariable("empId") int empId,Model model){
        boolean result = employeeService.deleteEmployee(empId);
        List<Employee> employees = employeeService.fetchAllEmps();
        model.addAttribute("employees", employees);
        model.addAttribute("listMsg", "<br>Employees List --- After Deleting Employee");
        return "redirect:displayAllEmps";
    }
```

URL: http://localhost:9876/SpringAnnotationDemo_Tomcat/deleteEmployee/displayAllEmps?listMsg=%3Cbr%3EEmployees+List+---+After+Deleting+Employee

The below is my jsp code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

    Welcome!!! ${myMap.DisMsg } ${listMsg}
    Context Path: <c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>
    <br/>
    requestURI: <c:out value="${pageContext.request.requestURI}"/>
        <br/>
    servletPaht: <c:out value="${pageContext.request.servletPath}"/>
<%--    Context Path: <c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>

    Context Path: <c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>

     --%>
    <br>---------------------------------------
    <br>

    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <!-- td>ID</td> -->
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td>Telephone</td>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach var="emp" items="${employees}">
            <tr>
                <!-- td>${emp.id}</td> -->
                <td>${emp.firstName}</td>
                <td>${emp.lastName}</td>
                <td>${emp.telephone}</td>
                <td>${emp.email}</td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value="getEmpForUpdate/${emp.id}" />">Update</a></td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value="deleteEmployee/${emp.id}" />">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

In the above code i have doubt that when i am redirecting from my controller method. why "deleteEmployee" is still there in the URL?

I think the URL should be like below.

http://localhost:9876/SpringAnnotationDemo_Tomcat/displayAllEmps?listMsg=%3Cbr%3EEmployees+List+---+After+Deleting+Employee

Please let me know what is the best practice to edit an existing record in the DB using spring MVC.

Comment: Because you are redirecting to a relative and not an absolute URL. Redirect to `/displayAllEmps` instead of `displayAllEmps`.

Comment: Please check my displayAllEmps() request mapping value. It has / then i think no need to add / in the retruning string. If that is the problem then it should not work in my @RequestMapping(value="/updateEmployee",method = RequestMethod.POST) also.

Comment: A redirect is clientside. So yes if you want to have it redirected to that it needs a `/` in the redirect so `redirect:/displayAllEmps`. It needs a full URL else it will do a relative instead of absolute redirect.